# Jquery bind to link, execute some post jquery then load link

Tags: jquery, post, callback

is there a clean way to bind a jquery post on a link and after the post is executed to load the link as it should do normally ?

here is my code:

```
$("a").bind('click', function(e){
     // disable click while we make a post request
     e.preventDefault();

     // make post request
     $.post('/blablabla/', { "datas" : mydatas } );
});
```

for now i disable click to allow my script to make a POST, but  I want the link bring to the target page after my POST is called and successfully executed. I think I need a callback but cannot find a good way to achieve it.

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a success function to your `.post` call which changes `window.location` to the `href` of the clicked link.

```
$( 'a' ).bind( 'click', function( e )
{
    var url;

    # disable click while we make a post request
    e.preventDefault();

    # get the url from the href attr
    url =  = $( this ).attr( 'href' );

    # make post request
    $.post(
        '/blablabla/',
        {
            datas: mydatas
        },
        function()
        {
            # send browser to url
            window.location = url;
        }
    );
} );
```

If you want the redirect to take place even if the POST fails, you could switch to using `.ajax()` and use the `complete` option:

```
$( 'a' ).bind( 'click', function( e )
{
    var url;

    # disable click while we make a post request
    e.preventDefault();

    # get the url from the href attr
    url =  = $( this ).attr( 'href' );

    # make post request
    $.ajax( {
        url: '/blablabla/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            datas: mydatas
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            # send browser to url
            window.location = url;
        }
    );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").bind('click', function(e){
    # disable click while we make a post request
    e.preventDefault();

    # Save the link url
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    # make post request
    $.post('/blablabla/', { "datas" : mydatas }, function() {
        # Post successful
        document.location(url);
    } );
});
```

You should prevent "double clicks" somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the url's href after the `$.post` returns.

```
$("a").bind('click', function(e){

        # disable click while we make a post request
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        # make post request
        $.post('/blablabla/', { "datas" : mydatas }, function(){
             window.location = url;
        });

});
```